# Chart: Red X Error when trying to display multiple series in an indexed chart

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, charts

I have an Issue with C# charting.

This is using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting

My series are configured to be indexed as such:

```
   {
          Name = name,
          Color = color,
          IsVisibleInLegend = false,
          IsXValueIndexed = true,
          ChartType = 
                  System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.FastLine
   };
```

I have 3 series in this chart

I am adding data to the series as it arrives via an Event Handler

```
for (int i = 0; i < samples; i++)
{
    double time_point = DData[i * 4]       
    chart1.Series[0].Points[lastSample + i].XValue = time_point;
    chart1.Series[0].Points[lastSample + i].YValues[0] = DData[i * 4 + 1];
    chart1.Series[1].Points[lastSample + i].XValue = time_point;
    chart1.Series[1].Points[lastSample + i].YValues[0] = DData[i * 4 + 2];
    chart1.Series[2].Points[lastSample + i].XValue = time_point;
    chart1.Series[2].Points[lastSample + i].YValues[0] = DData[i * 4 + 3];
}
lastSample = (lastSample + samples) % maxPlotPoints;
chart1.Invalidate();
```

The issue is as follows:

- If I turn on each series individually (via chart1.Series[0].Enabled), they all work fine
- If I turn on more than 1 series at a time, a big red X appears instead oft eh chart, and I have to restart the application to resume streaming charts. This either happens immediately or after a few seconds.
- If I set time_point to some other number, like 0, this issue doesn't happen, and all 3 charts can be displayed simultaneously

Next, I understand that this happens when each series has a different X-value for the same Point[] location. But I am explicitly setting all 3 series to use the same exact time_point

My next assumption was that the event handler was executing the tread before the previous thread finishes.

So I added a lock around the graphing call, it did not help

```
private Object thisLock = new Object();
lock (thisLock)
{

}
```

MY questions are:

1. Does anyone know if there is another reason why this may be caused?
2. Is it at all possible to use just the X-indexes from the first series for the chart but to display all 3 series simultaneuously?

Comment: _If I set time_point to some other number, like 0_ Is that 'like' or 'other than 0'? Also: The code you show only modifies DataPoints; it doesn't add them, right?

Comment: Correct. I created all the data points in order for the graph to stay the same length, and it just updates points from left to right (looks like an EKG scan). I can set time_point to any fixed number and it works, it's only when time_point continuously changes that it crashes. For example, if I do time_point++ after chart1.Invalidate() it will crash

Comment: Hm, one test would be to see if it has to do with the IsXValueIndexed property. You could set it to false before the updates and set it to true afterwards. btw: you only need to set it for one series.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This fix did not work, the problem disappeared, then came back after a while

The comment above by TaW helped me fix this issue.

This really seems to be a problem with Microsoft charts

I originally though it was due to EventHandler firing multiple times before it finishes, and I opted out to use a Queue that would be filled with an EventHandler and Dequeued on a separate thread.

The problem was still there.

The solution to the problem was to simply set IsXValueIndexed to **false**
then to set it to **true** before drawing the chart

Below is the code used

In case anyone is wondering what this does:
It graphs 3 Values simultaneously on the chart with increasing time. 
The chart updates from left to right instead of scrolling (think EKG machine in a hospital)
There is a fixed total number of points that is set to **maxPlotPoints** 
The EventHandler receives some Data packet (made up here) that contains a certain number of points which = **samplePoints**. 
It constructs a **DataPoints** struct and adds it to a queue

A separate thread **MainTask** dequeues an element from DataPoints and uses it to populate a 100 point section of each of the three series. That section then increments to the next 100 points, and so on.

This is useful if you want to continuously chart a fixed number of points

Unfortunately, I can't seem to mark the answer above from TaW as correct because it's in a comment. But I would be happy to try if you can explain how to do this. Thanks

```
    private struct DataPoint
    {
        public double timePoint;
        public double X;
        public double Y;
        public double Z;
    }
    private struct DataPoints
    {
        public DataPoints(int samples)
        {
            dataPoints = new DataPoint[samples];
        }
        public DataPoint[] dataPoints;
    }

    Queue queue = new Queue();
    int lastSample = 0;
    static int maxPlotPoints = 1000;
    static int samplePoints = 100;

    public ChartForm(UdpMgrControl RefUdpMgr, byte GyroChartNum, string ConfigFile)
    {
        for ( Row = 0; Row < 3; Row++)
        {   
            var series1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series
            {
               Name = name,
               Color = Color.Blue,
               IsVisibleInLegend = false,
               IsXValueIndexed = true,
               ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.FastLine
            };

            //Fill in chart with blank points
            for (int i = 0; i < maxPlotPoints; i++)
            {
                series1.Points.AddY(0);
            }

            chart1.Series.Add(series1);
        }

        chart1.Series[0].Enabled = true;
        chart1.Series[1].Enabled = true;
        chart1.Series[2].Enabled = true;

        running = true;
        Thread main_thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.MainTask));

    }

    private void OutputHandler(byte[] DData)
    {
        if (running)
        {
            DataPoints data_element = new DataPoints(samplePoints);
            for (int i = 0; i < samplePoints; i++)
            {
                data_element.dataPoints[i].X = DData[i].X;
                data_element.dataPoints[i].Y = DData[i].Y;
                data_element.dataPoints[i].Z = DData[i].Z;
                data_element.dataPoints[i].timePoint = DData[i].timePoint;
            }
            queue.Enqueue(data_element);
        }
    }
    private void MainTask()
    {
        while (running)
        {
            try
            {
                if (queue.Count > 0)
                {
                    chart1.Series[0].IsXValueIndexed = false;
                    chart1.Series[1].IsXValueIndexed = false;
                    chart1.Series[2].IsXValueIndexed = false;

                    DataPoints data_element = (DataPoints)queue.Dequeue();
                    for (int i = 0; i < data_element.dataPoints.Length; i++)
                        {
                            chart1.Series[0].Points[lastSample + i].XValue = data_element.dataPoints[i].timePoint;
                            chart1.Series[0].Points[lastSample + i].YValues[0] = data_element.dataPoints[i].X;

                            chart1.Series[1].Points[lastSample + i].XValue = data_element.dataPoints[i].timePoint;
                            chart1.Series[1].Points[lastSample + i].YValues[0] = data_element.dataPoints[i].Y;

                            chart1.Series[2].Points[lastSample + i].XValue = data_element.dataPoints[i].timePoint;
                            chart1.Series[2].Points[lastSample + i].YValues[0] = data_element.dataPoints[i].Z;
                        }

                    //Adjust the next location to end of first
                    lastSample = (lastSample + samples) % maxPlotPoints;

                    chart1.Series[0].IsXValueIndexed = true;
                    chart1.Series[1].IsXValueIndexed = true;
                    chart1.Series[2].IsXValueIndexed = true;

                    GC_UpdateDataGrids();
                    chart1.Invalidate();
                }
                else
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(10);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                LogErrors.AddErrorMsg(error.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Oh, and I found an additional problem.   Conditionally enabling and disabling the Series causes the crash as well. So I always have to set 
        chart1.Series[0].Enabled = true;
        chart1.Series[1].Enabled = true;
        chart1.Series[2].Enabled = true;